# How to get the TrackPoint sensitivity right on my Thinkpad X1 Carbon Gen 6 with Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: kubuntu, thinkpad, trackpoint

On my X1 Carbon Gen 6, the TrackPoint sensitivity settings in Kubuntu 20.04 are so off that my index finger is hurting on a daily basis from using it.

I've used the settings from [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/9hc02s/x1_carbon_6th_gen_trackpoint_issues_on_ubuntu_1804/) (X1C Gen6 w/ Ubuntu 18.04) which I believe work immediately after reboot, but I think after going into suspend, the default settings must be coming back.

Does anyone have any more up-to-date advice for adjusting the TrackPoint settings for (K)ubuntu 20.04?

Update: Running `xinput --list-props "TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint"` I get the following:

```
Device 'TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint':
        Device Enabled (172):   1
        Coordinate Transformation Matrix (174): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        Device Accel Profile (304):     2
        Device Accel Constant Deceleration (305):       0.500000
        Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (306):       1.000000
        Device Accel Velocity Scaling (307):    10.000000
        Device Product ID (296):        2, 10
        Device Node (295):      "/dev/input/event15"
        Evdev Axis Inversion (344):     0, 0
        Evdev Axes Swap (346):  0
        Axis Labels (347):      "Rel X" (182), "Rel Y" (183)
        Button Labels (348):    "Button Left" (175), "Button Middle" (176), "Button Right" (177), "Button Wheel Up" (178), "Button Wheel Down" (179), "Button Horiz Wheel Left" (180), "Button Horiz Wheel Right" (181)
        Evdev Scrolling Distance (349): 0, 0, 0
        Evdev Middle Button Emulation (350):    0
        Evdev Middle Button Timeout (351):      50
        Evdev Middle Button Button (352):       2
        Evdev Third Button Emulation (353):     0
        Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (354):     1000
        Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (355):      3
        Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (356):   20
        Evdev Wheel Emulation (357):    1
        Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (358):       6, 7, 4, 5
        Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (359):    2
        Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (360):    200
        Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (361):     2
        Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (362):  0
```

Comment: Hey Kent, you could follow these instructions to make your settings persistent: https://silvae86.github.io/2019/05/17/tuning-ibm-lenovo-trackpoint/. Can you try it out and see if it works?

Comment: I think those instructions only apply to older Thinkpads with Synaptics trackpoints, like the T420 in that thread, whereas the X1C gen 6 has something else. If, for example, I run `echo -n 175 > /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2/speed` I get "No such file or directory".

Comment: You are right, I got this working on my X1C gen 7 by running: `xinput --set-prop "TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint" "libinput Accel Speed" 1.0` where 1.0 is the maximum value. In order to get this working on startup,I added the command to Ubuntu Startup Applications. This solution should work for you as well.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue on my Thinkpad X1 Carbon Gen 7 on Ubuntu 20.04. I fixed it by running:

```
xinput --set-prop "TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint" "libinput Accel Speed" 1.0
```

This sets the acceleration to the maximum value which translates to better sensitivity.

To persist this on startup, I added the command to Startup Applications in Ubuntu.

You might also need to ensure that your `libinput` `Accel Profile` is set to "adaptive" and not "flat". You can test this by running:

```
xinput --list-props "TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint"
```

In the output you get, the `Accel Profile` enabled value should be:

```
libinput Accel Profile Enabled (315):   1, 0
```

**Additionally**, once you've set your acceleration profile, you can go to System Settings and set your mouse speed to maximum as well. The combination of the correct acceleration profile and mouse speed has made the trackpoint really smooth on my machine.

Comment: I'm guessing your config is closer to mine, but when I run the xinput command you list I get "property 'libinput Accel Speed' doesn't exist, you need to specify its type and format". Maybe I need to tweak it for the gen 6 version of the X1C?

Comment: Just run `xinput`. You'll get a list of all your devices - and you will find your trackpad in that list. Once you do that, run `xinput --list-props "<your-trackpad-name>"`. In that list you'll find the property value you need to set for Acceleration. I assume your device is not `TPPS/2 Elan Trackpoint `either.

Comment: It is named "TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint". I updated the question with the output of `xinput --list-props "TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint"`. Running `xinput --set-prop "TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint" "Device Accel Profile" 1, 0` fails but I'm able to set values ranging from 2 to 8. **I notice that using a value of 6 gets me a much more responsive TrackPoint.** I'll have to see about persistence but this is a definite improvement. Thank you.

Comment: @KentChristopher glad to hear it helped. For persistence using `Startup Applications` is the most straightforward way, although I'm sure others exist as well. 

if you found this answer helpful, can you upvote/accept so that it can be of help to others stumbling onto this question as well?

Comment: You could also configure your mouse speed to maximum in system stetings. The combination of max speed +the better acceleration profile has make the trackpoint experience a lot better for me.

Answer (score 2):

After "investing" 1 day of seeking for a functional solution, including tweaking `libinput` settings and installing `sysfsutils`, going back to `synaptics` showed up as the only way to keep my beloved trackpoint in action.

It seems to me that `libinput` is just not sophisticated enough and without properly set-up acceleration profile the trackpoint for me seems useless.

Found partial solution in this blog: [fixing the trackpoint on ubuntu](https://baach.de/Members/jhb/fixing-the-trackpoint-on-ubuntu)

1. Instal `synaptics` and remove `libinput`:

   ```
   apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-input-evdev-hwe-18.04
   apt remove xserver-xorg-input-libinput xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04
   ```
2. Add config file for X11: Create a `20-thinkpad.conf` file with the following contents in the `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` folder:

   ```bsh
   Section "InputClass"
   Identifier "Trackpoint Wheel Emulation"
   MatchProduct "TPPS/2 ALPS TrackPoint|TrackPoint"
   MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
   Option "EmulateWheel" "true"
   Option "EmulateWheelButton" "2"
   Option "Emulate3Buttons" "false"
   Option "XAxisMapping" "6 7"
   Option "YAxisMapping" "4 5"
   EndSection
   ```